# Extract data from grib weather model

Tags: mysql, gis, weather, grib, cdo-climate

I have downloaded `grib1` model data from [GFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Forecast_System), I am using a Mac OS X and was able to build the `wgrib2` file from [NOAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Oceanic_and_Atmospheric_Administration) but was unable to extract the data. I have not found a `grib1` utility for MAC.

Then I run to this program http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/ that was able to read the file and can see the data but I have some issues with it.

1. the values comes in other units  (like K for temp and other different from mm in rainfall)
2. I am able to export `CSV` but only the values not the coordinates

What I want to do is :

1. extract data from [grib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) file via the command line via latitude longitude
2. extract data an move to a `MySQL` database to be able to do some data aggregation (sum, max, min) etc
3. be able to plot / map data (I would probably use [CartoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CartoDB) service)

I already can extract `grib` or can download from certain region, I would like that data to be able to see on a spreadsheet for example latitude, longitude, temperature, rainfall, wind etc... then from there I can take it to a database, or sum /avg etc or manipulate data.

Sample `grib` data file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104462/neavilag_rain_wind_pressure.grb

Based on my scenario what is the best approach to handle my needs? Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: By 'MAC' you mean `Mac OS X`? What's `lat lon`? What database will you use (Oracle, PostgreSQL, Progress OpenEdge..)? What language/tool for plotting the data will you use? If you're looking for a script to transform the data from one format to another then providing a data samples would help

Comment: Hi, yes i mean Mac OS X, lat is latitude and lon is longitude. I will like to use mySQL, For plotting maybe use cartodb service but can be other you can suggest.. I already can extract grib or can download from certain region, I would like that data to be able to see on a spreadsheet for example latitude, longitude, temperature, rainfall, wind etc...  then from there I can take it to a database, or sum /avg etc or manipulate data. Maybe you can suggest me what to do. thanks...

Comment: here is a link to some data [link] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104462/neavilag_rain_wind_pressure.grb)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programmers to ask reasonably sized programming questions and find their answers. To keep your question [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) consider splitting it into smaller concrete questions each one tagged with a programming language. For complex orchestration you'll probably need to learn/use some Mac-friendly scripting language. Also consider using [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) site. I've no `gis` nor `macosx` experience so I won't help you any further

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to use [`cfgrib`](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib) which is a python based grib reader based on python project `xarray` and the `eccodes` software by the ECMWF.

It is very easy to use:

```
import cfgrib
cfgrib.open_datasets('your_grib_data.grib2')
```

And xarray comes with a lot of helpful built-in functions. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If I do this kind of manipulation I usually use CDO, as it handles all kinds of native grids correctly.  If you want to calculate the sum or mean of a field over a certain area for example, it is not correct to simply calculate the arithmetic mean with a regular lat-lon or reduced Gaussian grid as it does not account account for the changing grid-cell sizes as you move towards the poles.

I would therefore select an area with

```
cdo -f nc sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.grb out.nc
```

Here I am converting to netcdf at the same time with the "-f nc" option.  Many software packages read netcdf easily to create plots (ncl, gdl/idl, grads, R, python, panoply etc etc).

To calculate field statistics for the files it is as straightforward as

```
cdo fldmean in.nc out.nc
cdo fldmax in.nc out.nc
cdo fldsum in.nc out.nc
```

To give some of the examples you request. You may also make stats in the time dimension (timmean etc).  Check out the CDO help pages for details. I installed CDO on my MAC using macports.